Creating groups for a specific set of rows
I have this table



ProductID
Price
ID




90271
569
1


90271
455
2


90271
669
3


90271
535
4


90271
535
5


90271
535
6


90271
419
7


90271
300
8


90271
419
9


90271
419
10


90271
535
11



I need to add a GroupID column that groups the same prices under one GroupID before the next row changes the price. I can't simply use Dense_Rank() , because it creates the same GroupID for rows with ID 4,5,6,11.
Can you please advise me how to solve this?



ProductID
Price
ID
GroupID




90271
569
1
1


90271
455
2
2


90271
669
3
3


90271
535
4
4


90271
535
5
4


90271
535
6
4


90271
419
7
5


90271
300
8
6


90271
419
9
7


90271
419
10
7


90271
535
11
8




Always the same productid, no other products sold?

Yes, there are other products. I would need to group them all on the principle I have described.

Something like this SELECT sum(t.Price), t.GroupID FROM <table> t group by t.GroupID;  ?  Never put a column name with capital letters..

Sample data with different productid's make sense. How else could we know if the row (97000, 535, 12) should have GroupID 8 or 9?

this is basically a gap and island problem. You can use LEAD() or LAG() to compare the Price value and return 1 or 0. Perform a cumulative sum on that and it gives you the required GroupID
with cte as
(
  select *, 
         g = case when Price <> lag(Price) over(partition by ProductID 
                                                    order by ID)
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   thisTable
)
select *, GroupID = sum(g) over(partition by ProductID order by ID) + 1
from   cte


Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for
